# What is the $B^{-1}$ if $B^2 -5B + I = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think how I did it was that I did $B (B -5I) = -I$ and then divided both sides by $-1$ to get $B (-B+5BI) = I$ and then said $(-B+5I) = B^{-1}$.

Is this correct or is there a better way of doing it/answer?

Comment: $B^2-5B+I=0\implies B-5I+B^{-1}=0\implies B^{-1}=-B+5I$

Answer (score 4):

$$B^2-5B+I=0$$

$$I=5B-B^2=B(5I-B)$$

Hence $5I-B$ is the inverse of $B$. You have a minor typo of $BI$ but I think you have gotten the right concept.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the equation as $B^2 = 5B-I$ the multiplying by $B^{-1}$ on both sides gives so $B=5I-B^{-1}$ and so $B^{-1}=5I-B$.

Comment: Once you know  this, you can check that $5 I-B$ is the inverse of $B$, and you can do that without assuming in advance that $B$ is invertible.

Comment: @GEdgar I have a habit of using tacit assumptions in problems. I think it's a consequence of timed exams which encouraging me look for the path of least resistance.